# RSpec expectation is behaving strangely when retrieving value from input box and the value is a number

Tags: selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

I have a helper method that sets a value in an input box and then verifies the text afterward. However this fails if the value is a number. It looks something like:

```
def fill_in_value(label, text_input)
  textarea = find(locator of the input box, using the label passed into this method)
  textarea.set(text_input)
  textarea.value.should == text_input
end
```

However if `text_input` is a number, rspec expectations fails with `expected: 1 got: "1" (using ==)`

I am able to workaround this by doing something like:

```
text_input = text_input.to_s if text_input.is_a? Numeric
```

But that seems really clunky. Is there a way for me to properly evaluate the text inserted into the inputbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of any HTML field are going to be strings (even if it's a "number" field). You shouldn't need to do a conditional on `text_input`, just always do `text_input = text_input.to_s` since as the name of your parameter implies - it should be text.  Additionally you should never do `textarea.value.should == ...` that's a prime recipe for flaky tests. Instead you should use the matchers provided by Capybara

```
textarea.should match_selector(:field, with: text_input.to_s)
```

or if using the newer `expect` syntax of RSpec

```
expect(textarea).to match_selector(:field, with: text_input.to_s)
```

Comment: Thanks Tom! And thanks for the tip on writing better expectations.